# How to avoid intersection in pgRouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, route

I'm a newbie in pgrouting. I want to create a web-app with routing function. I want to ask how to avoid a road intersection with pgRouting? For example, there are some traffic jams happened in several road intersection and I want the route to avoid/exclude that road intersecton from calculation.

regards

Comment: One solution is but '-1' to cost to edges which cannot be used. That is only way i know not to use those edges. Another solution is make cost of those edges high enough. (assuming that you use dijkstra algorithm)

Comment: I plan to use A* algorithm, is that has a same condition?

Comment: If i recall it right, Yes . see http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/wiki/pgRoutingDocs.html